# mayapy: where's the graphics output?

Tags: maya

1. Find path to *mayapy* command (Maya's pre-configured external python interpreter)

   `$ locate mayapy   # result: /usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/bin/mayapy`
2. Launch the Maya-configured python interpreter in a terminal

   `$ /usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/bin/mayapy`
3. Create a sphere

   `import maya.standalone
   maya.standalone.initialize( name='python' )
   cmds.sphere( radius=4 )`

(this "works" and returns the following result:)

```
`[u'nurbsSphere1', u'makeNurbSphere1']`
```

**Q: how do I make this sphere show up in Maya (which I have open)?**

Comment: This may be a silly question, but why not just use the script editor?

Answer (score 3):

Each maya standalone session is it's own copy of maya - it is not connected to your open instance of  maya in any way . It's just like opening two maya sessions in gui mode at the same time.

if you want to connect to Maya from your IDE or outside, you can use the commandPort command in Maya to respond to packets sent over tcp (here's an [example using the Wing IDE](http://twistedsheep.com/blog/2012/10/11/remotely-sending-code-to-maya-from-wing), here's one [using Eclipse](http://nealbuerger.com/2012/07/eclipse-python-editor-maya-2013/)).  For more [complicated stuff you can use a remote procedure call library like  [RPyC](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/tut1.html#tut1) to remotely interact with the Maya session.

Comment: that's a darn thorough answer. you covered just about every option :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I created a new sphere in the currently open Maya using an external python.

1) open a port in Maya  (on the bottom of the screen there's a command line that says "MEL") and type:

```
commandPort -stp "python" -n ":5055" ;
```

2) open a python shell in a new window/terminal and run the following python code to create a new sphere in Maya:

```
import socket
maya = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
maya.connect(("127.0.0.1", 5055))
maya.send("""maya.cmds.polySphere( radius=4 )""")
```

The above code will create a new sphere in your currently running Maya. You can use any python terminal (doesn't have to be mayapy).

(If you're running python3, the last command will produce an error until you change it to:

```
maya.send(bytes("""maya.cmds.polySphere( radius=4 )""", 'UTF-8'))
```